# Keyboard and mouse becomes unresponsive on logon screen of Win 2003 Server

Tags: windows

I install my motherboard in another case.
Config is still the same.
Thought mouse and keyboard are different (I took what was at hand).
And now they totally stop to react exact after boot options screen.
What can this be?
I read inet. Some people say its because of drivers.

Update:
After trails I find that USB mouses working, but not USB keyboard.
Also changing driver (i8042prt.sys) file change nothing.

Weird.
And it quite inconvenient way to investigate -- to boot\reboot every time.
Is there some boot time tools for Windows?
Event Log shows nothing apropriate.
There was some system tool to check drivers...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the missed registry tree. I have copied it from another Windows 2003 computer and the problem is gone.  Here it is, below. (Save this as a text file with `.reg` extension and import in `regedit`).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Kbdclass\Parameters]

"ConnectMultiplePorts"=dword:00000000

"KeyboardDataQueueSize"=dword:00000064

"KeyboardDeviceBaseName"="KeyboardClass"

"MaximumPortsServiced"=dword:00000003

"SendOutputToAllPorts"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you booted your system in "safe" mode to test the drivers theory?

Comment: Yeah...  its the same

Comment: You might want to start removing non-essential hardware in troubleshooting any possibly conflicts or malfunctions. What was the reason for the motherboard swap in the first place?

Comment: I see a lot of similar questions on the net.

Comment: And there where is positive result it says that this problem resolves by itself...  khm

Comment: So is it now working?

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard / mouse are USB than I would try using a USB -> PS2 adaptor and see if that works. If not (as in your KB/Mouse are PS2 already) it wouldn't hurt to try USB alternatives. This may not give you the answer to the problem but if time is of the essence I would try this first and then troubleshoot what the problem was later. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I tryed with all I have and find a mouse that works, but not keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...  I find a cure for my case.
As it may be expected it was problem with registry.
I find previous "system" hive file and substitute existing with it.
And it fixed the problem.

Curses on mustdie   :))